# sed command to remove line if pattern matches and again find pattern in following lines then remove it

Tags: sed

```
compute_hosts:
  compute1:
    ip: 12.12.12.12
  compute2:
    ip: 13.13.13.13
#  compute3:
#    ip: 14.13.12.12
#  compute4:
#    ip: 12.23.34.45

metering-compute_hosts:
  compute1:
    ip: 31.13.13.23
  compute2:
    ip: 57.67.575.45
#  compute3:
#    ip: 32.322.4.35
#  compute4:
#    ip: 23.435.67.7
```

SED command to remove lines that is having compute 4 and its IP. IP must be search using pattern 
expected output :

```
compute_hosts:
      compute1:
        ip: 12.12.12.12
      compute2:
        ip: 13.13.13.13
    #  compute3:
    #    ip: 14.13.12.12

 metering-compute_hosts:
      compute1:
        ip: 31.13.13.23
      compute2:
        ip: 57.67.575.45
    #  compute3:
    #    ip: 32.322.4.35
```

compute 4 and its ip should be removed in the output

Comment: Not clear, please add more information on which lines should be removed and post the expected output too in code tags in your post too.

Comment: i have added what i am expecting

Comment: It is always recommended to add your efforts too in your post in code tags. So kindly do so.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please expose clearly your problem with a well-formed specific question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This sed will delete line with pattern and one line after:

```
sed '/compute4/,+1d'
```

Test:

```
$ sed '/compute4/,+1d' compute
compute_hosts:
  compute1:
    ip: 12.12.12.12
  compute2:
    ip: 13.13.13.13
#  compute3:
#    ip: 14.13.12.12

metering-compute_hosts:
  compute1:
    ip: 31.13.13.23
  compute2:
    ip: 57.67.575.45
#  compute3:
#    ip: 32.322.4.35
```

Comment: using this command i have already done this but we have to search  ip after compute 4 then remove that .. because may  be after next line of line that is having compute 4 is blank so ip must be removed using pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -re '/compute4/ {N;/\s+ip:/d}'
```

try this.

`N` joins the next input line in the pattern space

test:

```
$ cat compute | sed -re '/compute4/ {N;/\s+ip:/d}'
compute_hosts:
  compute1:
    ip: 12.12.12.12
  compute2:
    ip: 13.13.13.13
#  compute3:
#    ip: 14.13.12.12

metering-compute_hosts:
  compute1:
    ip: 31.13.13.23
  compute2:
    ip: 57.67.575.45
#  compute3:
#    ip: 32.322.4.35
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Since OP told next line of string `computer4` may NOT have IP so using this match function to match it in line first.

```
awk '/compute4/{flag=1;next} flag && match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){flag="";next} 1'  Input_file
```

---

---

Considering that your Input_file is same as shown samples, could you please try following(if you are ok with `awk`).

```
awk '/compute4/{getline;next} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Sir, awk is ok but ip must be search using pattern beacuse may be after next line of line that is having compute 4 is blank so ip must be removed using pattern

Comment: @J.Doerano, please check my EDIT solution now and let me know if that helps you?

Answer (score 0):

With awk following would work:

```
awk --posix '/compute4/,/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}/{next}{print}' input_file
```

- The range operator `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` keeps on returning *true* from the line which matches `/pattern1/` until the line which matches `/pattern2/`.
- We want to *exclude* the lines above; the following `{next}` works for it.

Comment: IMHO, I don't think they both string computer4 and ip addresses are coming in same line, so this may not give expected output, rest OP could tell more on this one.

Comment: The both strings will not come in the same line. The range operator works for the range of lines. I've tested the script with the assumed input according to the comment by OP. Or am I misunderstanging your comment?

Comment: What I thought by seeing OP's question they both are not in same line but it is my humble opinion rest OP can confirm.